# Searching a dictionary of words using difflib

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am trying to write a spellchecker and I wanted to use difflib to implement it. Basically I have a list of technical terms that I added to the standard Unix dictionary (`/usr/share/dict/words`) that I'm storing in a file I call dictionaryFile.py.

I have another script just called stringSim.py where I import the dictionary and test sample strings against it:

```
import os, sys
import difflib
import time
from dictionaryFile import wordList

inputString = "dictiunary" 
print "Search query: "+inputString  
startTime = time.time()

inputStringSplit = inputString.split()
for term in inputStringSplit:
    termL = term.lower()
    print "Search term: "+term
    closeMatches = difflib.get_close_matches(termL,wordList)
    if closeMatches[0] == termL: 
        print "Perfect Match"
    else:
        print "Possible Matches"
        print "\n".join(closeMatches)

print time.time() - startTime, "seconds"
```

It returns the following:

> ```
> $ python stringSim.py 
> Search query: dictiunary
> Search term: dictiunary
> Possible Matches
> dictionary
> dictionary's
> discretionary
> 0.492614984512 seconds
> ```

I'm wondering if there are better strategies I could be using for looking up similar matches (assuming a word is misspelled). This is for a web application so I am trying to optimize this part of the code to be a little snappier. Is there a better way I could structure the `wordList` variable (right now it is just a list of words)?

Comment: I had a similar issue with efficiency and used the Levenshtein module on pypi: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26894959/4085463

Answer (score 3):

Using `difflib` is probably the best choice. So the problem comes down to the size of your word list. If we can pare down the number of words `difflib` needs to compare, then we could get a faster time.

One idea to implement, is take only words that are *near-enough* in length:

```
# Returns the min and max thresholds for word length
def get_thresholds(word, min=3, max=3):
    length = len(word)
    return max(1, length-min), length+max 

# Returns only words whose length is within a certain range
def filter_word_list(min, max):
    return [word for word in words_list if min <= len(word) <= max]
```

So the call to `get_close_matches()` would be:

```
closeMatches = difflib.get_close_matches(termL,
                       dictionaryFile.filter_word_list(*get_thresholds(termL)))
```

Another idea would be to filter words that begin with a letter that is *spatially* related to the word's first letter on the keyboard. However, this suggestion is not as plausible due to different keyboard layouts.

As some general comments:

1. Take a look at your variable names. They are descriptive (for the most part) but the [official Python style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends using `underscores_between_words` instead of `camelCaseNames`.
2. Same basic idea for module names. Pythonic module names are written as `MyModule` instead of `myModule`. Also, each different module import gets its own line:

   ```
   # Not `import os, sys`
   import os
   import sys
   ```